# git revert affect in the history

Tags: git, revert

in the following image, when I git revert changeA, does my head stay at its original place and I have all the changes except for changeA?

Or I will loose all the changes from A to head and my head will be reset to the children of A ?

Sorry for the simple question in advance. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You will keep your history. What git revert actually does is add a new commit which undoes the changes of the specified commit.

source:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

[image]

Comment: so then to have the commit back again, do I do git checkout A ? by doing that do I get all of of history back as original?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to recommit that change you could git checkout A. You would maintain your whole history tree, including the history of your reversion. Your checkin would apply on top of the reversion, and would coincidentally have the same code as your reverted checkin.

Comment: @someguy Ist ist much simpler to revert the reverted commit again.

Comment: @A.H. I agree, I misread his question as 'Could I do this to resolve the issue?' rather than 'How should I resolve the issue?' Reverting the commit which reverted the functionality is easier and has the added bonus of being more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of them, it will create a new commit reverting the changes you made, keeping the your history.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert